# My friends cannot hear audio on my website while I can

Tags: html, audio

My website is and I have a song playing in the background. When I access the site I can hear the music, but when I tell my friends to go on they cannot hear the audio.

Seems they only not hear it when I use the audio tag. They can hear it when the audio is embed.

Comment: Seems they only not hear it when I use the audio tag. They can hear it when the audio is embed.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine in desktop browsers.

they probably use `ios` devices , safari disables autoplay, instead requiring that play be initiated as part of a user interaction (e.g., you can start playback within a touchstart listener). There's a bit of documentation about this on [Apple's developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html). There's also this article [Overcoming iOS HTML5 audio limitations](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/) on IBM's developer site that has examples and more detail.

Comment: right now im using an embed tag for my audio and my friends can hear it. Whenever I use the audio tag though they can no longer hear it while I still do.